# Find a word in a variable and render 1 else 0

Tags: sql-server

What is the best solution in finding a word in a variable? This needs to be within the Select statement, and if the word is found then '1' should be returned, else '0'.
Charindex or Regex?

I am trying something like this:

```
Select top 100
   [ReportingEntity]
   ,if CHARINDEX('Issuers', [ReportingEntity]) = '1' ELSE '0' END AS 'Issuers'
FROM [MSC].[dbo].[dsl_file]
```

And [ReportingEntity] can have variables like:

```
Tickert Issuers
Fund_Manager-Issuers
Issuers of Event 
...
```

Keen also to understand how that would work with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so with IIF, or CASE

**IIF**

```
SELECT TOP 100 [ReportingEntity]
    ,IIF(ReportingEntity LIKE '%Issuers%', 1, 0) AS 'Issuers'
FROM [MSC].[dbo].[dsl_file]
```

**CASE**

```
SELECT TOP 100 [ReportingEntity]
    ,CASE WHEN ReportingEntity LIKE '%Issuers%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Issuers'
FROM [MSC].[dbo].[dsl_file]
```